# Radare2 iaito: [Makefile:112: run] Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: linux, ubuntu-22.04, radare2

I am currently trying to compile iaito for Radare2 on Ubuntu 22.04 and am getting a segementation fault error when running `make run`.

Makefile line 112:
`rarun2 libpath=$(shell r2 -H R2_LIBDIR) program=$(BIN)`

Full output from make run:

`❯ sudo make run rarun2 libpath=/usr/local/lib program=build/iaito QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root' Plugins are loaded from "/root/.local/share/radareorg/iaito/plugins" Loaded 0 plugin(s). Plugins are loaded from "/usr/local/share/radareorg/iaito/plugins" Plugins are loaded from "/usr/share/radareorg/iaito/plugins" make: *** [Makefile:112: run] Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

No idea on how to fix this error, help.